# createBitmap not loading subimage correctly OR draw(Canvas) not displaying properly

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a resource, "cards.png" which contains all of the cards needed for a deck of cards.

The resource is exactly 896x352, and each card is exactly 64x88.

The "Card" object is a simple one, with a string for the suit, a string for the value, and a bitmap.

I use "Bitmap.createBitmap" to create a subimage from the big original one.
Later, when I draw, it did not appear that the function loaded the images properly.  Some cards are "offset" by a number of pixels, and it seems to get worse as I try to read the image from left to right.

I have tried everything, and found that there are a lot of unanswered similar questions here, so wondering if I am going about this the wrong way?

The resource "R.drawable.cards" is referenced in the "/game/res/drawable" folder.

The code for loading the card bitmaps is:

```
public GameScreen(Context context){
    int x=0, y=0;
    Bitmap cards = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.cards);
    for (Card card: deck.getCards()){
        if (card.getSuit().equals("C")){
            y = 0;
        } else if (card.getSuit().equals("D")){
            y = 88;
        } else if (card.getSuit().equals("H")){
            y = 176;
        } else if (card.getSuit().equals("S")){
            y = 264;
        } else {
            x=0;
            y=0;
        }

        if (card.getValue().equals("A")){
            x = 0;
        } else if (card.getValue().equals("10")){
            x = 576;
        } else if (card.getValue().equals("J")){
            x = 640;
        } else if (card.getValue().equals("Q")){
            x = 704;
        } else if (card.getValue().equals("K")){
            x = 768;
        } else if (card.getValue().equals("Joker")){
            // Joker
            x = 832;
        } else {
            x = 64 * (Integer.parseInt(card.getValue())-1);
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cards, x, y, CardBitmapWidth, CardBitmapHeight);
        card.setBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
```

The code to draw is:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (Card card: cards){
        canvas.drawBitmap(card.getBitmap(), x, y, null);
        x += card.getBitmap().getWidth();
        if (x>canvas.getWidth()){
            x = 0;
            y += card.getBitmap.getHeight();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Whaere is the bitmap referenced by R.drawable.cards? res/drawable-?

Comment: Yes, under "res/drawable".

Comment: res/drawable or res/drawable-something?

Comment: No, res/drawable only.

Comment: place it in res/drawable-nodpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the image is not being scaled when loaded:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap cards = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.cards, options);
```

Comment: yes, that makes sense, thank you.  But can I ask; what was it being scaled against?  I haven't yet drawn to the canvas, so what object was the function using when it loaded the bitmaps?

Comment: By default it scales the Bitmap at load time based on the pixel density of the target you are rendering to, instead of scaling when rendering it. By default the target density is just the screen density of the device you are running on, so on hi-res devices bitmaps get scaled up. More info in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html